# How to use sed, cut or awk to trim the 10th column to 30 characters globally, but skipping the header, then add a space plus 3 dots?

Tags: bash, sed

**Ubuntu 16.04

Bash 4.3.3**

Here is the header and the second line to a csv file.

```
"dealer_Id","vin","stock_id","mileage","year","make","model","body","transmission","engine","drive","interior_color","exterior_color","web_price"
"MP000","3GNCJPSB2KL130000","2190025","3","2019","Chevrolet","Trax","4D Sport Utility","6-Speed Automatic","ECOTEC 1.4L I4 SMPI DOHC Turbocharged VVT","AWD",
```

Here is my sed script to replace a few header names and some strings globally. I can replace the strings globally as I know they will never appear in the header names.

```
for feed in *; do
   sed -i '
      s/"stock_id"/"stocknumber"/;
      s/"body"/"bodystyle"/;
      s/"engine","drive"/"enginetext","drive"/;     
      s/"exterior_color"/"color"/;
      s/"interior_color"/"interiorcolor"/;
      s/"web_price"/"price"/;
      s/<b>//g; s/*//g;
      s/\([0-9]\)""/\1inch/g' "$feed"
done;
```

The header line is now perfect.

```
"dealer_Id","vin","stocknumber","mileage","year","make","model","bodystyle","transmission","enginetext","drive",
"MP000","3GNCJPSB2KL130000","2190025","3","2019","Chevrolet","Trax","4D Sport Utility","6-Speed Automatic","ECOTEC 1.4L I4 SMPI DOHC Turbocharged VVT","AWD",
```

The values in the 10th column are quite long:
`"ECOTEC 1.4L I4 SMPI DOHC Turbocharged VVT"`

We need to truncate it so it fits in the given space within the application without wrapping to the next line. So we figured if the 10th column has over 34 characters, we should truncate it to 30 characters then add a space plus 3 dots at the end of it so it looks like this:
`"ECOTEC 1.4L I4 SMPI DOHC Turbo ..."`

I can trim the 10th column globally like so:
`sed -r 's/([^,]{0,30})[^,]*/\1/10/g' $feed`

but I'm not sure how to add the space and 3 dots at the end of the truncated text while skipping the first line.

Comment: please ask only one question at a time. `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$5=substr($5,0,11)" ...\""}1'` does trim fifth field to 10 chars and trails a space and three dots

Comment: @oguzismail I'll open another one for the second question.

Comment: @oguzismail awk fields, array indices, and string character indices all start at 1, not 0. When you write `substr($5,0,11)` the `0` is an invalid value and so awk uses the default of `1` which is why you get the output you expect (except of course that to select 10 chars the 3rd arg should be 10, not 11).

Comment: @CuriousSam if you post a few lines of truly representative sample input and expected output then I'm sure you'll get an answer. Include at least strings that are 14 and 15 chars long as I'd expect the output for each to be interesting and different in terms of trailing dots. I mean, I understand why you need to truncate 15 chars but if your string is 14 chars long then why truncate it to 10 chars and add `" ..."` to get it to fit in a 14 char field when it would have fit as-is anyway? So please clarify your requirements and provide better sample input/output.

Comment: @Ed Morton, you are so right. That gave me so many ideas and now I will alter my question accordingly and hope I explain this better. I appreciate your guidance as always mate.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I have tried for you:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=`awk -F',' '{print $5}' test.csv | tr -d '"' | cut -b -10`;
b='"'$a' ..."';
z="$(awk -F,  -v fcol="$b" '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5=fcol,$6}' OFS=, test.csv)"
echo "$z" > someotherfile.csv
```

This will give you output as `"one","two","three","four","fivefivefi ...","six",`.